# What is the command to create a Magento crontab in Magento CLI 2.3?

Tags: magento2.2.3, crontab

I am using Magento 2.3 inside an UBUNTU 16.04 OS. I am trying to setup the cronjobs. 
In the documentation [official site](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html) the suggestion is `php bin/magento cron:install [--force]`. But as we can see in the picture the Magento CLI 2.3 the only available command is `setup:cron:run`. [image].
[image]
What is the actual command in order to create the crontabs in this Magento CLI 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `php bin/magento cron:install` is right command.

> It will add there files to cron job tab to your current SSH user.

*Then hit `crontab l` from the command line and outout  will be like below:*

```
#~ MAGENTO START
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END
```

Magento asking  **-f or --force**  aad suffix during the run of this command forcefully add cronjob to current command line user/SSH user.